# WCF Metadata reference cannot be resolved Error, WCF Service

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight

I have a WCF service issue. I made some changes to the service rename/added/removed services. Solution builds fine but when I reference this WCF service from a test solution...getting this error. It seems like there are some old references that haven't been removed. Looking for some feedback on how to resolve this. Thanks Jay

Comment: I assume you've done a clean and rebuild?

Comment: Yes, I have done the Clean/Build. It's odd that I can see the name of service in the Add Service Reference dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Use scvutil.exe to generate the service reference and then just add it as you would any other code.

Or even better, just directly reference the assembly(s) containing the service and type definitions and don't bother with the pre-generated proxy.

Appreciate this doesn't answer your question directly.

Comment: I get this error: The service cannot be activated because it does not support ASP.NET compatibility. ASP.NET compatibility is enabled for this application. Turn off ASP.NET compatibility mode in the web.config or add the AspNetCompatibilityRequirements attribute to the service type with RequirementsMode setting as 'Allowed' or 'Required'.

Comment: I get it after running scvutil.exe

Comment: Can you grab the wsdl and send it to me? Use command `svcutil /t:metadata http://my_service_address`

Comment: I am not able to pass along the full mesasge but it show more info about the error.

Comment: Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://localhost:114
1/Well/WellService.svc'.

    The server did not provide a meaningful reply; this might be caused by a con
tract mismatch, a premature session shutdown or an internal server error.

Comment: Another one, how do I enable metadata publishing. here is the message: If this is a Windows (R) Communication Foundation service to which you have acce
ss, please check that you have enabled metadata publishing at the specified addr
ess.  For help enabling metadata publishing, please refer to the MSDN documentat
ion at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=65455.

Comment: Your problem appears to be due to the service either not running or not being configured to enable WSDL publishing. Please start another question with these errors and I'll respond there.